# CRM 2011 - Product Lookup Error - "OK" button disabled after search in Lookup

Tags: view, customization, dynamics-crm-2011

We have a weird error/problem in our CRM 2011.  When we add a "Quote Product" and we want to choose an Existing Product, the "Ok"-button is grayed out when we do a Search for a Product. We can choose a product if we don't search, but not if we search on a particular product.

We have 3 environments at that particular client => DEV, UAT & PROD.  Everything works fine on the "DEV" & "UAT", but on the "PROD" we have the above problem.  So, I tried to export the "UAT"-customizations for the "PRODUCT" and import them to the "PROD"-environment, but nothings seems to happen.  The import was succesfull, but I the views weren't updated on the "PROD"-environment, even after the Publish.

Normally when we import from the on environment to the other environment, the views should be updated?

Does anyone of you guys had a similar problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved after that the ROLLUP 7 was installed!